# XAML/C# Do not close keyboard when hit AppBarButton in Windows Phone 8.1 Store App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I need NOT to close keyboard, when user finish input and tap on `AppBarButton`. How can I do that?

Currently, I use this code, but it just set focus back after triggering `Click` event on `AppBarButton`. It's bad solution.

```
private async void SendMessage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.MessageBox.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
    //my stuff
}
```

My XAML in case if it needed:

```
    <TextBox x:Name="MessageBox"
        Margin="0,10,10,10"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        Width="340"
        PlaceholderText="write a message..."
        InputScope="Chat"
        AcceptsReturn="True"
        TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <!-- -->
    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar >
            <AppBarButton x:Name="SendButton" 
                Label="Send"
                Icon="Send"
                IsEnabled="{Binding IsSendEnabled}"
                Visibility="{Binding IsSendVisible, Converter={StaticResource IsVisibleWhenDisabled}}"
                Click="SendMessage" />
        </CommandBar >
    </Page.BottomAppBar>
```

But how I can set keyboard to stay visible unless user hit Hardware Back Button or just tap somewhere?

Comment: In windows phone soft keypad can only be opened when textbox has focus. And when user presses any other button on the view focus go out of the textbox and the OS closes the soft key pad. The approach you are using is the only solution(the bad on). 

Why you do not disable the appbar button? it will convey a proper message to the user that they are not actionable anymore.

Comment: Try using Skype. When you hit "Send" keyboard does not close.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can 'force' the keyboard to stay on, when the keyboard loses focus it's fixed to be dismissed, what you might be able to do is to make the app set focus to keyboard

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.focus(v=vs.110).aspx